# Webpack won't compile Vue files in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, babeljs, webpacker

We have a Rails 5 project that is running webpack (through the webpacker gem) alongside the normal asset pipeline. Everything has worked like a charm for the past few months, until yesterday, for some reason, webpack stopped compiling our Vue files.

This is the error stack trace:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/Comments.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div class="comments-list">
|       <div v-for="comment in comments">
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/Comments.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/Comment.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div>
|       <div class="main-comment">
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/Comment.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/Autocomplete.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|     <div class="comment-box" v-bind:class="{'open':openSuggestion}">
|         <textarea class="form-control" type="text" :value="value" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/Autocomplete.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/cart.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|     <div class="container">
|         <div v-if="bundles.length != 0 || courses.length != 0" class="payment-section">
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/cart.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/itemCheckout.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|     <li class="course-checkout">
|         <a class="course-name"> {{ item.name }} </a>
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/itemCheckout.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/WishlistWindow.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div class="wishlist-window">
|         <div v-if="bundles.length == 0 && courses.length == 0" class="wrapper empty">
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/WishlistWindow.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/app.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div id="app">
|       <div class="new-comment-wrapper">
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/app.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/app.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div id="app">
|     <p>{{ message }}</p>
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js 9:0-29
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/quizapp.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div id="quizapp">
|     <div class="row">
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/quizapp.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/WishlistLink.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|   <div>
|     <li id="wishlist" @mouseover="showWishlist" @mouseleave="displayWishlist = false" :data-content="wishlistLength" > 
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/WishlistLink.vue

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/PayPalCheckout.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
| <div :id="id" class="paypal-button"></div>
| </template>
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/PayPalCheckout.vue
```

This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "lacerba",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This README would normally document whatever steps are necessary to get the application up and running.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.3.0",
    "autocomplete-vue": "^1.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.1.1",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000815",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "modernizr": "3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "videojs-mux": "^2.0.27",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.8.0",
    "vue-live-edit": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-loader": "^14.1.1",
    "vue-momentjs": "^0.1.1",
    "vue-paypal-checkout": "^2.1.8",
    "vue-stripe-checkout": "^0.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-typeahead": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "video.js": "^5.20.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ugolino/lacerba.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ugolino/lacerba/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ugolino/lacerba#readme"
}
```

I tried using different versions of webpack and/or webpack-web-server, however, it always ends up the same way. Although Babel is installed it seems like it's not able to read my .vue files.

It's worth mentioning that in the past months this has happened every once in a while and I've always just deleted the node_modules directory and run the **yarn** command that would install everything again from scratch and get rid of the error.

This is unfortunately not the case anymore. Any idea?

Comment: What other files are you referring to?

Comment: on app/javascript/

Comment: The application is fully configured. The application is live for months and just yesterday it started showing this errors when compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and mainly was due to webpack version.
I had webpack version 4.1.1 and my configuration was working with the 3.11
You can check your version with `webpack --version` 
After that re-run a `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` and `yarn install`
It worked for me